# In what Captain America comic did he kill a room full of villains?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, captain-america

I don't remember the issue number, but I remember it happened: Captain America killed a room full of villains with a machine gun, and I think he abandoned the hero business for a while after.

Which issue was this?

Comment: Is there any more information you can provide? This is pretty vague, and I bet Cap had done this dozens of times in the 75 or so years he's been around. Also, see [How to ask a good story-ID question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/13217)

Comment: This is probably **Captain America And The Falcon #1**

Comment: Don't close this, I have the answer.

Comment: It is not a perfect fit, but I suspect it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably **Captain America And The Falcon #1**

In this story, Captain America [mows down a  group of criminals with a machine gun](http://www.comicsbulletin.com/reviews/107894896943353.htm).

> When the Falcon looks to have violated federal law by breaking a
>   prisoner out of Guantanaamo Bay in Cuba, we see Captain America is
>   made aware of the situation. However, while it becomes apparent that
>   Sam may have had very good reason to break this person out of
>   Guantanaamo Bay, we see this doesn't stop Captain America from making
>   plans to head down after Sam. However, we see down in Cuba the
>   situation takes an unexpected turn as Captain America arrives to help
>   Sam by gunning down an entire room full of thugs.

And as the proof:

[image]
There might be an *eensy-weensy* twist on the next page.

Comment: A twist on the next page *is* bad news.

Comment: @Xantec How would that be?

Comment: Sorry, I was just playing off the last line in the comic you posted combined with your warning of a twist on the next page. i.e. "The good news is Captain America is on his way here. The bad new is--" "There might be an eensy-weensy twist on the next page."

Answer (score 1):

It could be Captain America #321 from 1986.
[image]

In the story Cap is forced to shoot an agent of Ultimatum, an organisation run by third string villain Flag-Smasher, to save several hostages.

The fact that he only shoots one man does not fit, but soon after this Steve Rogers is replaced as Captain America by John Walker who would later become U.S.Agent.